# reading YAML file and fetching values by iterating thru sections, keys and values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyyaml

I'm able to iterate a YAML config file and perform all actions needed for each section. Besides the nested for loops, is there any way that I could achieve the same results using a more pythonic code ?

```
import yaml
with open('/tmp/cfg_demo.yaml') as yfile:
    cfg = yaml.safe_load(yfile)

for header, subsections in cfg.iteritems():
    for section, key in subsections.iteritems():
        for values in key:
            for field, value in values.iteritems():
                if section == 'permission_assign':
                    # execute service to handle permissions
                    print section, field, value
                elif section == 'group_assign':
                    # execute service to handle group permissions
                    print section, field, value
                elif section == 'group_users_assign':
                    # execute service to handle user permissions
                    print section, field, value
                elif section == 'new_users':
                    # Execute service to handle user creation
                    print section, field, value
```

cfg_demo.yaml content:

```
access_management:
  permission_assign:
    - sample_1: service:1
    - sample_2: service:2
  group_assign:
    - sample_1: Group_1
    - sample_2: Group_2
  group_users_assign:
    - Group_1: User_a User_b
  new_users:
    - User_a: user_pwd
    - User_b: user_pwd
```

Output:

```
permission_assign sample_1 service:1
permission_assign sample_2 service:2
group_assign sample_1 Group_1
group_assign sample_2 Group_2
group_users_assign Group_1 User_a User_b
new_users User_a user_pwd
new_users User_b user_pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

As the keys `permission_assign`, `group_assign`, etc., are bound to do something more useful than printing with the ordered key-value pair information, I would create objects of different classes based on those.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from ruamel import yaml
from collections import OrderedDict


with open('cfg_demo.yml') as fp:
    cfg = yaml.safe_load(fp)


class SectionMap(dict):
    def add(self, cls):
        name = ''.join([n if n.islower() else '_' + n.lower() for n in cls.__name__])
        if name[0] == '_':
            name = name[1:]
        cls.name = name
        self[name] = cls

section_map = SectionMap()


class AssignedFieldValue:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.values = OrderedDict()
        for x in args:
            for k in x:
                self.values[k] = x[k]

    def dump(self):
        for k in self.values:
            v = self.values[k]
            print(self.name, k, v)


class PermissionAssign(AssignedFieldValue):
    pass
section_map.add(PermissionAssign)


class GroupAssign(AssignedFieldValue):
    pass
section_map.add(GroupAssign)


class GroupUsersAssign(AssignedFieldValue):
    pass
section_map.add(GroupUsersAssign)


class NewUsers(AssignedFieldValue):
    pass
section_map.add(NewUsers)

for header in cfg:
    subsections = cfg[header]
    for section_name in subsections:
        section = section_map[section_name](subsections[section_name])
        section.dump()
```

This prints the same as your output as you gave, but with a much simpler loop.

That way you get rid of the By extending the classes you can then add section specific, real, functionality. Just replace `section.dump()` with `section.do()` and implement a method `do()` for each of the `AssignedFieldValue` subclasses.

If you can change your YAML, then I would change it to include tags:

```
access_management:
  - !permission_assign
    sample_1: service:1
    sample_2: service:2
  - !group_assign
    sample_1: Group_1
    sample_2: Group_2
  - !group_users_assign
    Group_1: User_a User_b
  - !new_users
    User_a: user_pwd
    User_b: user_pwd
```

based on appropriate constructors and using `round_trip_load()` (which preserves the order of the key-value pairs) you can load this YAML and directly generate the sections, without the need for the `SectionMap()` stuff. That is both more Pythonic and makes better use of YAML features.

---

Please note that `iteritems()` is gone in Python3 and so is `print` as a statement. The above code will run in both Python 2 and 3